# Svelte path to a static folder

Tags: path, svelte, sveltekit

I use Sveltekit and put some images in my static folder. Static > images > image1.png etc.

Within source, src, I have a folder called `lib` and inside `lib` a folder called `components` and in there a file `Footer.svelte`. In that file I want to reference to my image1 (which has an absolute path of `~/myapp/static/images/image1.png`. Even when I try this path it throws me an error.

So:
`src > lib > components > Footer.svelte`

`static > images > image1.png`

Both `src` and `static` are in root dir of `myapp`.

And this line in my `Footer.svelte`:
`import Image from '~/myapp/static/images/image1.png';`

Whats the correct line in my `Footer.svelte` for grabbing `image1.png`?

See in problem description.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Files in `static` are not supposed to be imported, they should be
available as static files directly on the root of the application so you can reference them as:

```html
<img src="/images/image1.png" />
```

If you want to import an image, I would suggest putting it in `src/lib` and import from there via:

```js
import image from '$lib/.../image1.png';
```

```html
<img src={image} ... />
```

This also adds a hash to the asset in the build output, making sure that the cache is invalidated if the content of the image changes later. Would only use the static directory for things like `robots.txt` which requires a fixed path.

(The mapping of the `$lib` alias is created by SvelteKit, one can also configure [additional aliases](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#alias). There is also a [`files` config](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#files) where one can change the path of `lib` and other directories. You also can import from other locations, e.g. put the image next to other files of a route if it is specific to that route.)